# Cycle2: Links disappear after first time through

Tags: jquery-cycle2

I'm using cycle2 on my page. Everything works correctly the first time each slide is displayed. Once it gets to it's second+ iteration, the CTAs 'drop' their clickability. Mousing over the visible CTA does nothing. Interestingly, it registers the CTA from the next slide, even though it's hidden. 
My z-index is highest for the visible slide. Any ideas on what's happening?

Page: https://kasasa.com/home/b2b-v3.html

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, in Cycle2 z-index of currently active slide is not always the highest. Actually, starting from the second cycle, the highest z-index has previous active slide, which is currently hidden.

In your case, links from current active slide are just covered (starting from the second cycle) by invisible elements from the previous slide.

The solution is to separate slides and their data. You may use either built-in Cycle2 Overlays (see http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/caption2.php) or, if you need more complex templates, build your own solution using Cycle2 Events (see http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/).

Comment: Interesting! this is essentially The code we used http://codepen.io/leetech/pen/layLu, though we broke it apart to fit our CMS. Is the execution different enough from the caption plugin that it would solve the z-index issue?

Comment: I think this is exactly what you need. Only set z-index of `.cycle-caption` to something greater than 100 - then your caption will be always on the top and you can use any links in its template.

Comment: I've sketched this out and it works, though what about handling 'complex' captions? Our current text is 3 individual spans.

Comment: I don't understand, what's the problem? :) Your codepen example contains just 3 individual spans in a caption... You need to remove `<span>` tags from your `<li>` slides and add `data-cycle-caption1/2/3` properties instead...